# Actors: Thread based vs Event driven

Tags: actor

Reading about actor based programming, I came across thread based actors and event driven actors.

What's the difference between two? And when to use which?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Actor Model itself is a concurrency specification.  From the Actor Model perspective, there is no concept of "events", "threads" or a "processes", only Actors and messages.

This is actually one of the benefits of the Actor model in that it takes a different approach to concurrency that provides greater isolation.  Any shared information must be exchanged via messages and the processing of a particular message is atomic, so no special concurrency synchronization techniques are required during execution of an Actor's message handler.

By contrast, threads run in a shared memory space, which requires careful coordination of memory updates (via mutexes and locks) or simulated exchange of information (via queues... with locks or mutexes).  Processes implement a concurrency model that is more similar to Actors in that they provide more isolation, but do not have native support for message exchange so the information exchange must often be constructed and managed within the process via pipes or sockets and corresponding protocols and resource management; Actors provide this message exchange functionality "out of the box" as it were.

Practically speaking, most Operating Systems provide the "process" and "thread" concurrency implementations instead of Actors, so the Actor framework you utilize will need to map your Actors onto the operating system's underlying concurrency model.  Some do this by implementing each Actor as a separate thread, some by implementing Actors as separate processes, some by using one or more threads and iterating through the set of Actors to pass messages.  Even event-driven implementations such as Beam (the Erlang VM) will need to perform this mapping if they wish to utilize multiple processor contexts and there is an Operating System between the VM and the hardware.

When you write your Actors, you are writing to that concurrency abstraction and should not be concerned with any concurrency model remapping handled by your Actor Framework: that is the purpose and the purview of the framework.

Unfortunately, since the OS manages the system resources, and the OS's concurrency model (along with your language) is usually built around a thread and/or process model, you will need to consider the effect of the mapping when working with system resources.  For example, if your Actor is written in C and will be making a blocking read() syscall on a file or socket, an event driven model will cause *all* Actors to halt, whereas a thread- or process-based Actor model should allow the other Actors to continue processing while the other Actor is blocked on the read() call.  I this same scenario but using CPython (for example), both an event-driven and a threaded Actor model would still block all other Actors due to the CPython GIL, but a process-based Python Actor model would still be able to allow concurrent Actor execution.  Many Actor Frameworks will provide additional functionality to help maintain the Actor model abstractions when using system resources, so you will need to check the details of your Framework when writing Actors that interact with OS-managed resources (especially in a blocking manner).

Some Actor Frameworks are capable of changing the implementation mode based on startup configuration parameters (e.g. running as event-driven, threaded, or process-based depending on a start parameter).  This can be very useful; for example, simple testing using a cooperative, single-threaded implementation allows repeatable and understandable test results while the production application still runs with full concurrency and no modifications.

In general, when writing Actors you should try to use Actor-based concurrency practices and migrate any external interfaces that might be affected by the underlying implementation to the edge of your design where they can be easily redesigned if needed.